# How to remove purple/magenta vertical bar in left margin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

Visual Studio Code 1.71.0 on mac os monterey 12.5

I've been seeing a vertical purple bar in the left margin, left of line numbers, when something is changed on the same line for all file types.  When I save the page, the bar does not go away.  I cannot insert or remove a breakpoint on the bar once the bar is visible.  If I close the file and then reopen, the bar goes away.

I've tried disabling extensions and I've commented out any custom settings. I think this area of the editor is call the glyph margin.  I can hide the entire margin, but I need to use breakpoints.
What is the purple bar and how do I remove it?
thanks

VS Code editor image